# A Problem Related to the Sylvester-Gallai Theorem

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry

The **Sylvester–Gallai theorem**  states that every finite set of points in the Euclidean plane has a line that passes through exactly two of the points or a line that passes through all of them.

I am trying to solve a related question to the theorem but I am not able to do it.

**Question:** Let $n$ distinct points are drawn in the plane such that all of them do not lie on
a line. (1) Draw all possible lines through at least two points. And (2) Prove that there are at least $n$ lines.

Any help and references would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried induction on $n$?

Comment: @saulspatz Not yet. I don't really know how to approach the problem, am still new in the field. Further hint or insight into the question will be of great help.

Comment: Suppose the theorem is true for $n$ points, and you are given $n+1$ points.  Remove any one of them.  What can you say?  You don't need the Sylvester-Gallai theorem to do this.  You just need to know how induction works, and that two points determine a line.

Comment: @saulspatz Silvester-Gallai is useful for the induction step :)

Comment: This is the [de Bruijn–Erdős theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_theorem_(incidence_geometry))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do it by induction, as suggested by saulspatz (though Silvester-Gallai is in fact useful here).

The base case $n=3$ (with not all points on the same line) is clear.

Now if $n\geq 3$ and we are given $n+1$ non-collinear points, by Silvester-Gallai we know that there is a line $L$ with only two points on it. Remove one of those two points, so that the remaining $n$ points are not collinear (*). By induction hypothesis the remaining points determine at least $n$ lines (*but $L$ is not one of them*!). So the original $n+1$ points determine at least $n+1$ lines.

---

(*) this is always possible: if taking away one of the points (say, $A$) makes the remaining $n$ points lie on the same line $G$, then $A$ can't also lie on $G$ (since the $n+1$ points are non-collinear) and we may remove the other point instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I just did the proof in my head, and there was a mistake in it.